# Provisioning Mode fails for existing app but works on a newly created one

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, provisioning, scim

Trying to edit provisioning mode in an Azure Enterprise App through SCIM but keep getting the error below:

[image]

Funny enough I created another app to test the same credentials and the credentials work. I am wondering what could be the issue with this current app. Below you can see I am not even able to change the provisioning to manual, it's stuck on automatic:

[image]

Anyone familiar with this in Azure deployment?

1. List item

Comment: Did you wrote SCIM endpoint by your own? Or maybe used some of the existing Micorsoft solutions like https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode ?

Comment: Used existing material.

Comment: What logs on your api side are talking about? Do you know what type of the request is sent? Could you compare test requests from working and not working apps within your SCIM endpoint? That would give you some more information.

Answer (score 0):

That error shows when you've customized your mappings / schema and set something invalid such as including Id as a target attribute or you have decided to primary keys in the advanced settings.

Select the check box for restore default attribute mappings and clear state and restart and save.

Comment: Under mapping it says mappings are invalid, if one tries to restore to defaults it still requires the credentials for the account in order to save the settings. Seeing that the credentials are not being saved because it is indicating it it wrong then this change cannot be made.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. That design needs to be improved. You can use graph to delete the job. Sign into graph explorer as a global admin to delete the job and you will be able to authorize access again and get the default configuration on the old app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http